# Google PageSpeed Enable Compression isn't working?

Tags: javascript, plugin-w3-total-cache, cache, compression

I am trying to improve pagespeed of my website. When I test my site it tells "Compressing https://z-1-static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yF/r/SQ7jeOqw5xW.js could save 188.3KiB (70% reduction)." I have W3 Total Cache installed and enabled gzip compression. But still it's showing the same issue. How can I edit compress this file as it's out of my control. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Does your server support compression?

Comment: Yes. after viewing phpinfo(), I have known that gzip is enabled. As there is                                       gzip compression  enabled

Comment: Look up `phpinfo()` or ask your host.

Comment: Yes, it's enabled.gzip compression  enabled . But how will I compress this js file which is situated in Facebook?

Comment: You can't compress a file served by code you don't control.

Comment: Then why Google is showing this if I can't control it! I have seen if I remove that facebook like button then the score improves by 10. (from 69 to 79).

Comment: You are seeing all requests for the page including requests made to remote sites out of your control. It sounds like you need to learn a bit more about websites work.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum, did you noticed the recommendation of Google "Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network."

Comment: No argument but ***you are requesting a resource from a Facebook controlled domain***!  Unless you have significant pull at Facebook this is beyond your control. If Facebook doesn't want to serve it compressed it isn't going to get served compressed. It isn't that complicated. Maybe via Facebook's API you can do something but I don't know.